# How to reinstall the appcompatv7_11 package in android?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-appcompat

So, I had to have my laptop restored, and now when I open my eclipse workspace, my appcompat_v7_11 package has an error in it, and now some of my apps have errors all over the place because of it. I need to reinstall the appcompat package or at least restore the 7_11 package back to the way it was. I want the proper way of doing this, that way I don't end up deleting the wrong files, duplicating the same files, or anything else that will make the problem worse. Thank you in advance.

EDIT: So I realized that each of my appcompat files are assigned to each one of my apps. So obviously my appcompat file 7_11 must have been messed up when my computer was restored. Is there a way to fix or restore this file that way I won't have 100 errors in my app?

EDIT 2: This is the error I get:

Errors occurred during the build.
Errors running builder 'Android Resource Manager' on project 'DayManager'.
java.lang.NullPointerException
Errors running builder 'Android Resource Manager' on project 'appcompat_v7_11'.
java.lang.NullPointerException

If you know of any android help centers that may help me, please post them, as I can't continue my app development without fixing this problem.

EDIT 3: I've noticed that it is missing the Android 4.4.2 and Android Private Libraries

Answer (score 1):

I am replying to the thread a year later but hope this helps others who might land up here with this query.

This is what worked for me

Go to Project and select Clean on your eclipse tool

This video helped https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fp-hiJrTROU
There are more tips here